# How to define percentage of result items with specific field in Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a search query that returns all items matching `users` that have type `manager` or `lead`.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "type": ["manager", "lead"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to define what percentage of the results should be of type "manager"?

In other words, I want the results to have 80% of users with type `manager` and 20% with type `lead`.

Comment: Hi, Do you have a numerical field or date field in your mapping? I want to make you a solution but I need to know do you have a such field in your documents or not.

Comment: @SaeedNasehi yes, I have another date field in the mapping

Answer (score 0):

I want to make a suggestion to use `bucket_path` aggregation. As I know this aggregation needs to be run in sub-aggs of a histogram aggregation. As you have such field in your mapping so I think this query should work for you:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "my_datetime",
        "interval": "month"
      }, 
      "aggs": {
        "role_type": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "type",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "_id"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "role_1_ratio": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "role_1": "role_type['manager']>count",
              "role_2": "role_type['lead']>count"
            },
            "script": "params.role_1 / (params.role_1+params.role_2)*100"
          }
        },
        "role_2_ratio": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "role_1": "role_type['manager']>count",
              "role_2": "role_type['lead']>count"
            },
            "script": "params.role_2 / (params.role_1+params.role_2)*100"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if it didn't work well for you.

Comment: Hi, Did you check this solution? did it work for you.