# Is it possible to have pipeline aggegation in sub-aggs of aggregation other than histogram and date_histogram?

Tags: elasticsearch

I wanted to have a pipeline aggregation which is described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#buckets-path-syntax). In all examples, the `bucket_path` aggregation is just running in a query that has a `histogram` or `date_histogram` aggregation. Why this is just working in this way? Is there any way to perform `bucket_path` in a query with other aggregations such as term aggregation?

Comment: `bucket_path` is not an aggregation per se but a setting of pipeline aggregations. Maybe show what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I faced this issue when I wanted to answer to this question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576472/how-to-define-percentage-of-result-items-with-specific-field-in-elasticsearch-qu?noredirect=1#comment121198711_68576472). I just wanted to use `bucket_path` to be able to produce percentage of occurrence of documents.

Comment: It's definitely possible to have a bucket_script pipeline aggregation as a child of a terms aggregation. Probably others too.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.